# Dynamic vertical stripes in DIV using css and/or SASS

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I'm trying to figure out how to create up to 4 vertical stripes on the background of a DIV. Each stripe is 4 pixels wide and is the same h=height as the div. Also I need to have the stripes be dynamic. There could be any number of the 4 stripes visible at runtime based on some data in an object.

Here's an image of the general idea.

[image: Sample div with stripes]

I've been trying to implement this with css and sass as well as javascript but not making progress. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please include your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am correctly understanding your question, `box-shadow` might help you solve this problem. Here is what I have tried,

- Initialize a div with some height and width
- Now we have psuedo elements `:before` and `:after` use it to create strips, i.e 2 strips will appear.
- Now, `box-shadow` comes into picture for every strip you can `n` number of strips using `box-shadow` .

Here is my attempt.

```css
.progress{
  width:140px;
  height:40px;
  background-color:white;
  border:2px solid black;
}
.progress::after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:4px;
  height:inherit;
  background-color:red;
  box-shadow:4px 0 lightgreen
}
.progress::before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:4px;
  height:inherit;
  background-color:blue;
  left:18px;
  box-shadow:4px 0 pink
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="progress"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This looks great.  Now I just need to create these stripes dynamically in Javascript based on the data in the div. I'm half way there. Thanks

Comment: @Brent... thanks, if it is really helpful, mark it as accepted! comment here if you want any help

Comment: Yes this was very helpful. The hardest part will be creating these striped in code at runtime. Sometimes there will be a red stripe. Sometimes a blue stripe and sometimes all stripes will be visible. I was researching SASS variables for this right now

Comment: @Brent... What do you actually want to do? Can you please tell me, so that I may help you out

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have 4 Javascript boolean variables as follows: BlueStripe, RedStripe, GreenStripe, and PinkStripe. I then test each var and if its True I add the stripe to the div. I could see any number of stripes in the div at runtime based on these boolean variables.

Comment: @Brent... I couldn't get the sentence `I have 4 Javascript boolean variables as follows` Where are they? or else ask a new Question

Comment: These true/false variables are in the script for the web page and a function will run every time the page is refreshed. Maybe a function like this DrawStripesinDiv(blueStripe, redStripe, greenStripe, pinkStripe);

Comment: This is an interesting article that I'm looking at now. Maybe I could make the width of each stripe a SASS variable and default them to 0px. If the stripe is to be visible then set the SASS variable to 4px in Javascript. [link](https://eager.io/blog/communicating-between-javascript-and-css-with-css-variables/)

Comment: @Brent... yes! but can I ask you what are you going to do?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your previous question. I was going to try my idea by looking at that link unless someone has a better idea and/or some code already written.

Comment: I'm going to mark this one as solved and thank you for your effort on this one. I'll create a new issue If I can't figure out the dynamic Javascript part myself.